# System will not tether via USB to Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: networking, usb

I am currently attempting to tether my system (running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) to my Samsung Galaxy S7 edge via USB. However, when I enable USB tethering on the phone, the system does not connect to it, nor is the new connection recognized in the network listing. The relevant `dmesg` logs when I enable tethering are as follows:

```
usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 52
usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 53 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6863
usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 3-4: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
usb 3-4: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
usb 3-4: SerialNumber: ebb0c96c
rndis_host 3-4:1.0 eth1: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, RNDIS device, 00:00:00:00:00:00
rndis_host 3-4:1.0 enp0s20u4: renamed from eth1
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u4: link is not ready
```

Indeed, `enp0s20u4` is recognized in `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether bc:5f:f4:a2:6a:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 02:42:ea:7c:cb:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: enp0s20u4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

However, as stated, the link does not appear to be recognized anywhere else. Further command output can be provided upon request.

**How can I properly tether my system to the phone via USB?**

Comment: This `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u4: link is not ready` might be the issue see https://serverfault.com/questions/520920/ipv6-addrconfnetdev-up-eth2-link-is-not-ready-ipv6-addrconfnetdev-up

Comment: @George I don't think the accepted solution there would fix my issue, I've been running the latest kernel headers and whatnot

Comment: Have you checked that the cables are plugged in well?

Comment: @George Yes, the phone is physically plugged in to the system via USB.